# NameError: name 'MAKE_CLOSURE' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

При попытке использовать byteplay3 на питоне 3.8:

```
>>> import byteplay3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/byteplay3.py", line 400, in <module>
    hascode = set( [ Opcode(MAKE_FUNCTION), Opcode(MAKE_CLOSURE) ] )
NameError: name 'MAKE_CLOSURE' is not defined
```

как исправить?

Comment: Решить эту проблему можно путем понижения Python до 3.7, так как он не работает с 3.8

Comment: Так никто мне и не ответил на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо единственное решение использовать питон 3.7.